# Bash Script accepts that with multiple prompts

Tags: bash, shell, githooks

I'm trying to create a **post-checkout** git hook and have the a bash script that will run `composer update` and `php artisan migrate:refresh`, Since I'm just beginning with bash scripting I can't figure out why my script doesn't execute the 'Run Migrations' part?

```
#!/bin/bash
exec < /dev/tty

while true; do
    read -p "Run Composer Update[Y/n]: " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) composer update; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac    
done
while true; do
    read -p "Run Migrations[Y/n]: " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) php artisan migrate:refresh; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac    
done
```

Comment: You probably want `break` instead of `exit`.  Saying `exit` would exit the script which is why the _Run Migrations_ part is not executed when you say `n` to the first.

Comment: If user pressing `y` in first while and then its not going in second `while` then its an issue, else you have your answer in first comment.

Comment: The question was answered by @devnull 's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break` instead of `exit` in the "No" option

```
#!/bin/bash
exec < /dev/tty

while true; do
    read -p "Run Composer Update[Y/n]: " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) composer update; break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac    
done
while true; do
    read -p "Run Migrations[Y/n]: " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) php artisan migrate:refresh; break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac    
done
```